# Do I need a Pull type solenoid or Push type?

Tags: solenoid

I have building a device that will use a solenoid. The solenoid will be used such that it will be mounted in the floor and when a stick is put over it, it will start vibration. That vibration needs to be felt by the person holding the stick. I learned of late that solenoids are are of two type i.e. Pull an Push.

Can someone please tell what's difference between two & which I need for my above described project. I personally think I will require a Push type solenoid. As I need the vibrations to be felt so by the observer so that say she can count those.

Comment: Why are you using a solenoid instead of an offset weight motor?

Comment: I have no info about an offset weight motor. I thought of a speaker vibration & solenoid mechanism is working there so I go for it.Can you put some link about offset weight motor so that I may read about it.

Comment: An offset weight motor, is just a regular motor, with a weight that's lopsided. It literally throws it's weight around to make things vibrate. Like the motors used in cell phones to make them vibrate.

Comment: I search for it but donot find any link. can you please share some link about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither. A solenoid isn't a vibrator. If you insist on using one anyway, either will serve, but you need to handle the mechanics differently for each one, with a spring to handle the return.

Comment: If I use solenoid, I am thinking about push type as I need the vibrations to be felt so by the observer that say she can count those. So for that effect as I think a push type can serve as it will push the stick upward with force. 
Yes, it's vibration that I want & I found solenoid as solution. I will have to program a micro controller to generate required vibrations. Can you please suggest some other equipment for generating vibrations in this case?

Comment: If all you want is something to bump up that a person can feel, then a push solenoid pointing upward would work (no need for a spring return- gravity will do that).  A simple push button switch could close a circuit and fire the "bumper" without need for a microcontroller.  What exactly are you doing?  It sounds like a medium getting fake spirit readings or something...

Answer (score 1):

Try a search for "pager motors."   They're tiny little motors with an offset weight on the shaft.   Using enough of them might rattle the teeth out of your mouth!   :)

Posted elsewhere: ([What is good device for generating vibrations, offset weight motor or solenoid or some other?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/75495/what-is-good-device-for-generating-vibrations-offset-weight-motor-or-solenoid-o))