# sophisticated push type solenoid needed for vibrational output-Push type Tabular ??

Tags: solenoid

I am looking for a sophisticated push type solenoid. By sophisticated I mean I can control its plunger movement to move following a pattern by a micro controller, over a stroke length of about 10mm.

I have had so far pull type solenoid because I learned lately that I need actually a push type. But these appear good for heavy duty work of moving rapidly. The size (height) I need should be around 4-5 cm. It will be very helpful for me if someone please refer me some. It should operate under 12V on DC. It should be able to push half to one kg weight. Stroke length of about 10 mm. Please refer me to some supplier too.

**EDIT**
From videos on the net, I realized that push type tabular solenoid is probably good option for vibrational output. Courtesy to this video [Push Type Tabular Solenoid Video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4GhIPVjKwX0)
(comparing to my pull type open body solenoid movement).
**But**   I found from search on net so far that there are not many distributors of push type tabular solenoids (& moreover most what I found are in China, so far). Does open body push type solenoid also move like same or not? Though I feel like tabular type is good option.

Any reply in this regard will help me.

Comment: What type of movement control are you trying to achieve?

Comment: In a comment below you've mentioned "control of vibrations" so I assume this is related to your previous "vibrating stick" questions? The answer below is perfectly valid based on the current question and I've just upvoted it, but I doubt that a linear actuator will be any more suitable for that purpose than the solenoids / speaker coils you've mentioned in the past if it is the same project.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Do I need a Pull type solenoid or Push type?](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/75484/do-i-need-a-pull-type-solenoid-or-push-type)

Comment: @s3c yes vibration i.e. linear movement,the only movement solenoid performs.Like control on time difference between two consecutive linear movements, like it vibrate once then wait for 1 second then vibrates twice & waits for 2 second & then thrice & three second wait,any random pattern etc.I can do it with current solenoid I have but that's is not much sophisticated.By sophisticated I mean less control I feel like on this linear movement.So if there is some specific assembly/model of solenoid I am looking.Linear actuator which I know now seem having control on linear movement.Plz reply.

Comment: @PeterJ I come to know about linear actuator courtesy to this post. From info & videos I see about actuator,it seem like doing what I mean by sophisticated control over linear movement.Can you plz just reply I need to perform a patterned linear movement & yes for same 'stick vibration' project.Time difference between linear movement pattern can be like one vibration then hold for one second then vibrate twice and hold for two seconds and so on random.I think movement force can also be controled by LA.Are they available in small size that of a 4,5 cm height.

Comment: @AnindoGhosh I am thankful for your earlier precious suggestions, but this is not a duplication of same.

Comment: @enterprize, I've never personally seen one that small, but they are basically a motor that turns a screw, so the other problem is that most take something like a second to fully extend, I can't see them vibrating well. Maybe you need one of those plus an offset weight motor.

Comment: For short-distance relatively fast vibrations what about using a subwoofer loudspeaker? There are plenty of powerful subs out there with amps to drive them, easily capable of moving +/-10mm with some force, just need an audio-level waveform to drive them.

Answer (score 2):

I unfortunately can't point you to the direct model to use but I believe what you are looking for isn't a solenoid, for one I've never seen a solenoid with a long stroke length that long. Linear actuators do what you require and can often be precisely controlled. I've used large models in the past able to move objects over 100kg, never a small one I could recommend though.

Comment: Yes it does sound like a linear actuator the OP wants

Comment: @s3c sorry, typo error. not 10 cm but 10 mm. It is a guessed valued basically.Not need to be precised enough.What I am basically concerned is control on vibrations.

Comment: @s3c: (I edit OP too)From videos on the net, I realized that push type tabular solenoid is probably good option for vibrational output. Courtesy to this video Push Type Tabular Solenoid Video.http: //www.youtube.com/watch?v=4GhIPVjKwX0
But I found from search on net so far that there are not many distributors of push type tabular solenoids (& moreover most what I found are in China, so far). Does open body push type solenoid also move like same or not? Though I feel like tabular type is good option.
Any reply in this regard will help me.

Comment: The large manufacturers stock a variety of solenoids, I'd recommend you order a couple of the cheaper types and play around to see exactly what will or will not work in your scenario. http://uk.rs-online.com/web/c/automation-control-gear/solenoids/tubular-solenoid/